# Generating configuration file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that output's configuration for my hadoop/spark cluster. I am using following command to output the configuration file.

```
python generateHadoopConfig.py
```

How do I pipe this output to a temp file in same directory, for my EMR cluster to fetch it for updating the configuration.

Comment: Why doesn't the command you are using work? The name suggests it does exactly what you want. What is missing?

Comment: What does `generateHadoopConfig.py` do? Is it just outputting the config to `stdout` via calls to `print`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the script outputs the config file? Then just pipe it to a file like this:

`python generateHadoopConfig.py > myconfig.conf`